# Why do the ajax requests fire multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, request

I have a form inside a modal that either saves a memo when one button is clicked or deletes it when another is clicked. The items get saved/deleted but the request count multiplies with each click.  I'm getting 4 of the same request etc. How do i stop this. do i have to unbind something?

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var origin = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var memoId = origin.attr('data-id');        

    $('#modal').click(function(event){
        if($(event.target).hasClass('memo-save')) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var memoText = $(event.target).parent().parent().find('textarea').val();

            var memo = {
                memo: memoText,
                id: memoId
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/memos/add-memo?memo=' +memo+'&id=' + memoId,
                data: memo,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(event.target).toggleClass('active').html('Memo Saved');
                }
            });


        } else if($(event.target).hasClass('memo-delete')) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var memoText = "";

            var memo = {
                id: memoId
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/memos/remove-memo?id=' + itemId,
                data: memo,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(event.target).toggleClass('active').html('Memo Deleted');
                }
            });
        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can move the `$('#modal').click` outside the `$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal'` that way it will not re-add the listener each time the modal is shown